# How to uplift a call?

Tags: android

I was wondering if anyone knew how to uplift a call or what code or settings would allow me to do this in my own app:
https://youtu.be/Xtxt-D0FEuk?feature=shared

I'm looking at how to do this on Android.

I have been doing some google searches, but I haven't found anything on how to do what is shown in the youtube video.